# A function call misbehaves in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, function, arguments, call

I use PostgreSQL 10.3.

I have created the following domains:

```
CREATE DOMAIN common.citext_nullable
    AS extensions.citext;

CREATE DOMAIN common.citext_not_null
    AS extensions.citext NOT NULL;

CREATE DOMAIN common.smallint_ge_zero_nullable
    AS smallint;

ALTER DOMAIN common.smallint_ge_zero_nullable
    ADD CONSTRAINT smallint_ge_zero_nullable_check CHECK (value >= 0);
```

and the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION common.fun_name(
        p_1    common.citext_not_null,
        p_2    common.citext_nullable,
        p_3    common.citext_nullable,
        p_4    common.smallint_ge_zero_nullable)
    RETURNS ...
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
    DECLARE
        ...
    BEGIN
    ...
    END;
$BODY$;
```

Notes:

1. All parameters/arguments are of **domain** types.
2. Domains and functions are in the same schema "common".
3. The schema "common" is included in the search path.
4. All extensions are in the schema "extensions".
5. The schema "extensions" is also included in the search path.
6. "citext"-based domains work as expected.
7. "smallint"-based domain works strangely.
8. The above domains and function are simplified for the scope of the question.

I can call the function either by

```
SELECT fun_name('any', 'any', 'any', 5::smallint_ge_zero_nullable);
```

or even by

```
SELECT fun_name('any', 'any', 'any', '5');
```

but I cannot call it by:

```
SELECT fun_name('any', 'any', 'any', 5);
```

I get the following error:

```
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function fun_name(unknown, unknown, unknown, integer) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 8
```

Why "citext"-based arguments are shown as "unknown"? As per doc, page 1431

> **argtype**
>
> The data type(s) of the function's arguments (optionally schema-qualified), if any. The argument types can be base, composite, or domain types, or ...

(It is "funny" the "**unknown**" arguments, in the end, to be accepted and work as expected and the "**integer**" argument not to be accepted and behave strangely.)

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is related to int - smallint casting and not to the domain.

You can find the rules for associating a function call to the function with the proper parameters [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/typeconv-func.html). It will use implicit cast when available and will always match 'unknown' types to anything. Since you have only one signature for your function, case 1 (explicit cast) and 2 (all unknown) will be matched to your function.

There is no automatic down casting, so integer -> smallInt won't occur implicitely. Let's think about a function having two signatures `f(input as int)` and `f(input as smallint)` If downscasting was to occur, which one should be used when calling `f(5)`? This mailing-list [thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/C0FE28B9352B6F4F8CE371643EC3B25121083555%40EFJDFWMB01.EFJDFW.local) will give more details.

So the solutions are to either
- do the explicit casting (case 1)
- or to have a function wrapper with the generic types (integer) that do the casting for you (and handles errors..)
- or to call the function with the output of a table column having the proper type.

Comment: In the case I describe there is not ambiguity! 5 complies with the argument type (`smallint`) of the function. So, in fact there is an internal code weakness (bug). Arguments and domains do not work as logically expected! Anyway, thanks for the solutions you have mentioned.

Comment: @SONewbiee No, it is logical for your function, but not for ALL functions. Implicit cast are used everywhere in the DB, and automatic down-casting would lead to issues all over the place